# Deploy React on Cpanel => Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, cpanel

I need help to install my react project with Cpanel *(O2switch host)*. See my project :

[image]

For my server I use `Sequelize` to manage ma data base.

I followed steps provids on the web :

**Step 0 :**
Create the database *(if you need it)*.

**Step 1 :**
Add into `package.json`, contains into my `client` file, the following code : `"homepage": ".",`

[image]

**Step 2 :**
`npm run build` into my `client` file to create `build` file *(in red into the previous picture)*.

**Step 3** :
Make a `.htaccess` it will look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 4** :
Create my nodeJS server on Cpanel

[image]

**Step 5** :
Go inside my `Cpanel > file directory > monGouvernement` :

[image]

And add into `public` all files from my `build` file.
After, add all files from my `server` file as below *(without node_modules file)* :

[image]

**Step 6** :
Go back to my nodeJs_setup to click on "Run NPM install" to install dependencies and create `node_modules` files.

At this step, my database is created. But my front-end doesn't work. See what my browser show me:

[image]

I don't understand the reason of it. Could help me to solve this issus please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok I solved my problem.**

The answer is : I didn't add my `build` file at the right place. On my O2Switch Cpanel I'm hosting my domaine name and my nodeJs server *(that I created with the setup_NodeJs_app)*. So, I got two files in my `file manager` :

[image]

The **first** one is for my domaine name. The **second** one is for my nodeJs server.

So I have to add my `build` file into my domaine *(mon-gouvernement.fr)* name like this :

[image]

And my server files into the other one *(monGouvernement)* :

[image]

Like this, everything work perfectly.